# How to get dynamic no of tables using json

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I want to create Jasper Report with Dynamic no of tables.
FOR EXAMPLE:

- User 1 - 5 tables
- User 2 - 3 tables
- User 3 - 6 tables

I tried with list option but my tables are not visible and number of pages are getting increased.

```
<subDataset name="tableDataSet" uuid="c72d8dbd-d63e-411b-862d-a0d6e1e25d37">
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[tableData]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="listDataSet" uuid="c72d8dbd-d63e-411b-862d-a0d6e1e25d37">
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[listData]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="tableData" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[tableData]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[mainDataSet]]>
</queryString>
<field name="listData" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[listData]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<componentElement>
<reportElement x="-1" y="170" width="830" height="150" uuid="ab0272db-d740-42c9-94e5-238a2cc4a63e"/>
<jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
<datasetRun subDataset="listDataSet" uuid="f80306fb-80fc-405b-b90d-f9fe6b6ee2e1">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("listData")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
<jr:listContents height="150" width="830">
    <componentElement>
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="67" width="825" height="76" uuid="6a8e89c4-d4ea-4d8f-b932-8fbb24d00725"/>
<jr:table>
    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataSet" uuid="6ab7d349-34c8-4db7-bf3c-4e638ca36f5c">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("tableData")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:column width="100" uuid="aae649c4-6a69-485f-8a0d-87022df793ee">
    <jr:columnHeader style="colBotLeftLine" height="30">
        <staticText>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
        <textElement>
            <font isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnHeader>
    <jr:columnFooter style="footerBotLeftLine" height="20">
        <staticText>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
        <textElement>
            <font isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Grand Total]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnFooter>
    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
        <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="734834e8-5896-4355-9454-6b188e86bfff"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        </jr:detailCell>
    </jr:column>
</jr:table>
</componentElement>
</jr:listContents>
</jr:list>
</componentElement>
```

**Json Data.**

```
{mainDataSet :
 [
  {CompanyName : "XYZ",
   listData:
    [
     {tableId:1,
      tableName:"Table One",
      tableData:
        [
        {description:"Table One Row Data One "},
        {description:"Table One Row Data Two"}
        ]
     },
     {tableId:2,
      tableName:"Table Two",
      tableData:
        [
        {description:"Table Two Row Data One "},
        {description:"Table Two Row Data Two"}
        ]
     }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

`mainDataSet` is my Report Data Set, `listData` is the data for list and `tableData` is the one i want to display in my tables.
**NOTE**

 If I remove the

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("tableData")]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

and put

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Then Two tables are created with null values.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Probably the .subDataSource("tableValues") is wrong but its impossible to answer if you don't post both your ListDataSet and an example of your data.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I have updated the question with listDataSet and the JSON data

Comment: Ok, I have posted and answer using that datasource.. your sure it the same??? or are there other tags outside of this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query to main report let's leave it blank (and keep the mainDataSet node)

```
<queryString language="json"><![CDATA[]]></queryString>
```

Define the `CompanyName` field as

```
<field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mainDataSet[0].CompanyName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

The `dataSourceExpression` to pass to the `jr:list`

```
<datasetRun subDataset="listDataSet" uuid="71276e30-7777-44ae-b6d9-2087a4c51ca3">
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("mainDataSet.listData")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

Hence point to the `mainDataSet.listData`

The `dataSourceExpression` to pass to the table (we are now in the `listData`)

```
<datasetRun subDataset="tableDataSet" uuid="5bca90cb-1473-4ff6-82fc-1da5ae4fb44c">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("tableData")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: But i cannot leave the main report query blank. I need to display the Company Name

Comment: How to you pass the JsonDataSource to the main report?

Comment: `<queryString language="json"><![CDATA[mainDataSet]]></queryString>` was giving the company name.

Comment: I meant from java how are you passing the JsonDataSource... if that gave company name, keep it, but also keep the mainDataSet.listData, we are having different datasource... maybe there are other tags before, what are you doing in java?

Comment: `InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( jsonStr.getBytes()); JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(is,"mainDataSet");` I'm filling the data by giving the `mainDataSet` name

Comment: `<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("tableData")]]></dataSourceExpression>` did the magic and now it's working fine.

Comment: Perfect I update my answer added the CompanyName in report, but I can't exactly replicate your datasource.