# Jasper Report - Passing json IO stream to subreport

Tags: json, jasper-reports, iostream

I have a working report with subreport which uses a json source file as data source. In this for subreport I send the path to the json file in subReportParameter `net.sf.jasperreports.json.source`

However, if I use JSON IO stream as data source instead of json source file, how do I pass the data source to the subreport? For a single report, JSON iostream works well but cant figure out how to use subreport here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `json` from `InputStream`, I will make and example using an **url**, since this seem's to be the most probably use.

The **java** code to generate the `JsonDataSource`

```
InputStream iostream = new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php").openStream(); //Natrually this code is not need if you already have the iostrem
JsonDataSource dsSupReeport = new JsonDataSource(iostream);;
```

How do I pass it as parameter (lets do **2 examples in one**), passing the whole `JsonDataSource` or just the `String` value of the `URL`

**In java** setup your `parameter`s that you like to pass to your report (fillManager)

```
Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
paramMap.put("datasource", new JsonDataSource(new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php").openStream()));
paramMap.put("urlToDataSource", "http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php");
```

**In report** setup the parameters with correct class

```
<parameter name="datasource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="urlToDataSource" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

And then use them the `dataSourceExpression` using the `JsonDataSource` is:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{datasource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

or using the `String` value of an url

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JsonDataSource(new URL($P{urlToDataSource}).openStream())]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

**NOTE**: You can use subdataset if your data is already present in main datasource (no need for new JsonDataSource). [Example of subdataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778753/dynamic-no-of-tables-in-jasper-report/33802364#33802364)