# How to iterate over JSON array to create repeating report in jasperreports

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I have a JSON data with a following structure

```
[{
"a1":"b1",
"a2":"b2",
"details1":[{"a1":"b1"}],
"details2":[{"a2":"b2"}],
},
{
"a1":"b1",
"a2":"b2",
"details1":[{"a1":"b1"}],
"details2":[{"a2":"b2"}],
},
{
"a1":"b1",
"a2":"b2",
"details1":[{"a1":"b1"}],
"details2":[{"a2":"b2"}],
}]
```

I have created separate reports for details1 and details2 arrays.
Also I have create a report for one element of the main table refferring to details1 and details2 reports as a subreports.

The problem is the main report is printing only the a1 and a2 from the first element and then prints all elements from all details1 and details2 tables from all elements.

My goal is to create a report that will print a1,a2, details1, details2 from first element of the main table, then the second one and so on. How can I achive that?

In other words, how can I iterate the same report template over the JSON array?

Comment: Can you show an example what you result you like to get?, so we understand exactly what is your problem is, normally you create a new datasource using subDataSource, see [How to get dynamic no of tables using json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778753/how-to-get-dynamic-no-of-tables-using-json) and [Jasper subreport showing only one entry from the JSON data source when embedded in the Title band](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399255/)

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for the advice. I've managed to resolve my issue by putting everything (static, dynamic fields and two subreports) in my report to custom group. I am not sure if I should post an answer or just delete my question. ?

Comment: I think you should improve your question and post answer (specially since other users has posted answer), Try to make it useful for future users, hence a question that anyone can answer without opinions and a nice answer on how you solved it. If you don't have the energy well then maybe we can close it as duplicate (I personally don't like deleting stuff that other user have put in energy to answer)

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to create subreports in order to reach the nested arrays. A simpler solution is to make use of `subDatasets`.

In your case you need to create subDatasets for each details key in your JSON source:

```
<subDataset name="details1" uuid="4563e834-a9e5-43b5-9f0a-824948c73c73">
  <field name="A1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a1]]></fieldDescription>
  </field>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="details2" uuid="f703cb76-2a4a-44f1-9a42-227e180038d2">
  <field name="A2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a2]]></fieldDescription>
  </field>
</subDataset>
```

Your main query has to be empty in order to iterate over each object in the main JSON source:

```
<queryString language="json">
  <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
```

You then need to use a structure that knows how to handle a subDataset like a table or a list. I'm choosing a list here since it easier to work with. For the first subDataset you would then have:

```
<componentElement>
  <reportElement x="90" y="40" width="333" height="20" uuid="c3237c70-6b2e-43e3-aa21-5092d8b91afc"/>
  <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
    <datasetRun subDataset="details1" uuid="f5fdc6a3-736f-43ce-b549-cd7332d19eb8">
      <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("details1")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:listContents height="20" width="333">
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="07e3ff2a-3832-4b06-9275-cb1ee8e51cfe"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A1}]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
    </jr:listContents>
  </jr:list>
</componentElement>
```

For the second subDataset the list component is identical.

Here is a simple JRXML with the complete solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="81afe112-ee1b-4443-8d1c-cb6d9ab95dd8">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JsonArrayDataAdapter.xml"/>
  <subDataset name="details1" uuid="4563e834-a9e5-43b5-9f0a-824948c73c73">
    <field name="A1" class="java.lang.String">
      <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
  </subDataset>
  <subDataset name="details2" uuid="f703cb76-2a4a-44f1-9a42-227e180038d2">
    <field name="A2" class="java.lang.String">
      <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
  </subDataset>
  <queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[]]>
  </queryString>
  <field name="A1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a1]]></fieldDescription>
  </field>
  <field name="A2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[a2]]></fieldDescription>
  </field>
  <detail>
    <band height="99" splitType="Stretch">
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="72" y="16" width="100" height="24" uuid="698866c8-7d26-4bc7-8727-b4a56d239a53"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A1}]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="190" y="16" width="100" height="24" uuid="e775c6c0-4058-4bc4-8c7a-d4d381fd6e66"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A2}]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <componentElement>
        <reportElement x="90" y="40" width="333" height="20" uuid="c3237c70-6b2e-43e3-aa21-5092d8b91afc"/>
        <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
          <datasetRun subDataset="details1" uuid="f5fdc6a3-736f-43ce-b549-cd7332d19eb8">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("details1")]]></dataSourceExpression>
          </datasetRun>
          <jr:listContents height="20" width="333">
            <textField>
              <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="07e3ff2a-3832-4b06-9275-cb1ee8e51cfe"/>
              <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
          </jr:listContents>
        </jr:list>
      </componentElement>
      <componentElement>
        <reportElement x="90" y="60" width="333" height="20" uuid="38f3ac11-ad3e-464c-813a-46132f23783f"/>
        <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
          <datasetRun subDataset="details2" uuid="833a13c3-e9b8-4f56-9f8f-279d32d403e8">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("details2")]]></dataSourceExpression>
          </datasetRun>
          <jr:listContents height="20" width="333">
            <textField>
              <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="3d9fb513-bfc9-4d95-a3da-16b95cf15e7c"/>
              <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
          </jr:listContents>
        </jr:list>
      </componentElement>
    </band>
  </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I try to use the above example but its print the null value on the page